# Почему эти теги выравнивают все по центру?

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование

Здравствуй ХешКод, у меня тут возникла проблема, и не знаю как её вылечить. У меня есть файл head.php в котором подключается файл function.php так вот у меня в этом файле был скрипт(javascript) проверки данных, но потом я его решил удалить. И после удаления этого кода, у меня почему-то весь текст на всём сайте выравнивается по центру, хотя в скрипте, было только 1 регулярное выражение на проверку введенных чисел, а после удаления всё опять по центру, причём что когда я удалил всю фунцию проверки и оставил только

```
<script></script>
```

Без ничего, всё нормально, но стоит удалить эти пустые теги, опять по центру.

Вот пример как это видит W3: [самая первая ошибка](http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fangus123.24-hoster.ru%2Findex.php)

Answer (score 1):

Неправильный порядок следования тэгов:

```
<script></script><!DOCTYPE html><!DOCT
```

Скрипт должен быть либо в head, либо в body, но не перед доктайпом.
Измените место вставки скрипта, а еще лучше вынесите в отдельный файл js.

Comment: Ну так вот я пытаюсь убрать этот тег вообще(он мне не нужен), и при удалении все выравнивается по центру...

Comment: Значит скорее всего Вы изначально делали разметку своего сайта опираясь на то, что браузер натыкается на ошибку в самом начале страницы и парсит ее после этого как одному Ктулху известно, а не как положено.  
Измените стили так, чтобы все отображалось как Вы хотите.

Comment: Кто такие Ктулху?